# Minor x ticks below, major above

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have the minor ticks of the X axis below the `Axes`, and the major above?

With the following code, I can draw both minor and major ticks on the same side, but I'd like to have the `0` and `5` ticks located above the plot, while the minor ticks stay below.

```
from matplotlib import figure as mpfig
from matplotlib.backends import backend_agg as mpback


fig = mpfig.Figure()
mpback.FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(10))

ax.set_xticks(list(range(0, 11, 5)))
ax.set_xticks(list(range(0, 11, 1)), minor=True)

ax.plot(x, y)
fig.savefig("picture.png")
```

This code produces the following picture:

[image]

I know of [`Axes.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html), and I expected to find such an option there, but I didn't find any.
I also know of [`Axes.tick_top`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.tick_top.html) and [`Axes.tick_bottom`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.XAxis.tick_bottom.html), but they move both minor and major ticks to the same side.

I'd like to avoid any trick with `Axes.twinx`, since it would add a new `Axes` object which would make the drawing heavier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Axes.tick_params` should be able to solve this.

```py
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',top=False,bottom=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',top=True,bottom=False)
```

On trying, this worked for me:

```py
from matplotlib import figure as mpfig
from matplotlib.backends import backend_agg as mpback


fig = mpfig.Figure()
mpback.FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = list(range(10))
y = list(range(10))

ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',top=False,bottom=True)
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='major',top=True,bottom=False)

ax.set_xticks(list(range(0, 11, 5)))
ax.set_xticks(list(range(0, 11, 1)), minor=True)

ax.plot(x, y)
fig.savefig("picture.png")
```

Comment: Oh right, it definitely works. I guess I did not understand the doc... Thanks!

Comment: No worries! :) .